Why is it a english-language question?
I had a question about being sceptic about optical observations.
Check silver gaze in mirrors
But its closed because it is about english-language.
How is it about the english language?

The question was closed as it lacks a notable (or any) claim.
The banner states:

Questions are required to show that the claim is notable

This is explained in the link within the banner as:

References in questions are used to provide evidence that a claim is
notable. We don't expect the sources to be scientifically valid, but
to demonstrate either a lot of people have heard of the claim, or that
some notable person(s) make it.

Then there's your question there lacking a claim (and a link to a source for that claim):

state or assert that something is the case, typically without
providing evidence or proof.

From Oxford Languages.
Please note that you making a claim, or a friend telling you something, or "I heard" - these do not count as notable claims as there is no indication that they're widely believed.
In the comments, I suggested that you might perhaps look at our english.se site as the question seemed to me to be based on the meaning of a phrase that is unfamiliar to myself. You clarified in an edit that the phrase was of German origin, and that silver-gaze was a direct translation of a German single-word-agglutination, an idiom, for which there may not be an equivalent meaning in English.
It was pointed out that before posting on english.se, you should take the tour and read-up in their help center to ensure that your question is on topic. You should also include any definition of the phrase, with sources.
I'd further add, the question as it stands seems to contain at least one misunderstanding of a common English word:
Squint: "To squint means the eyes focus something on your nose" - this is incorrect. To squint is to almost close your eyelids:

To look with the eyes partly closed, as in bright sunlight.

From Wordnik, the first definition, all others are related to this one, not the meaning you speak of.

The evidence is inside the question. Squinting have multiple meanings, as you can read in wikipedia (cite: "For the medical condition which causes crossed eyes, see strabismus.") the question claims "To squint means the eyes focus something on your nose." This distinctively means the strabismus and you know that because you wrote (which isn't meant for literal interpretation). You closed for off-topic and commented suggested to post at english-language. They wont answer the question. You understood the question. But instead of improve the question, you closed it. That is offensive.

The notability is demonstrated in the question. I can not tell who closed the question. As far as I could tell, you would close the question for the same reason instead of edit the question. You showed no effort of suggest a better word either till now. I did not say you are offensive, I wrote that close instead of improve is offensive.

"The notability is demonstrated in the question". That is not the case in reality. We require that a source be provided from a medium (newspaper, widely-read article) that demonstrates that the claim is widely believed. There is no cited source, there isn't a claim either. The question was in my view correctly closed as off-topic. It seems to be very unfocussed too as it doesn't seek to challenge any claim, but to seek an explanation of a not clearly specified phenomenon, relying on a translation of a term not familiar in English. We don't provide explanations, we verify/disconfirm claims.

"I can not tell who closed the question." I believe you can tell by checking the timeline, but you need to be very responsible with that information. There have been a number of incidents of people harassing users over their decision to close a question, hence why that information is hidden away.

Welcome to the Skeptics.SE. We have some unusual rules here about what makes a question on-topic.
Here is more information about how we work.
Your question was written in an unclear manner, and did not appear to be on topic. I have deleted it; I didn't think it was salvageable.

I already reat them.
